# Yet Another Java GUI Calculator

Tags: java, calculator, community-challenge

In the spirit of [April 2015 Community Challenge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5174/april-2015-community-challenge?cb=1), I have created *two* Java-based calculators with the following codebase layout:

- An interface `Calculeightor` for describing how values can be appended into a stream and then reduced to a single result given an operator.
- An enum `Operator` to represent the operators.
- The GUI implementation `CalculeightorGUI`.
- The CLI implementation `CalculeightorCLI`.
- A unit test for the CLI implementation `CalculeightorCommandLineInterfaceTest`.

The name uses `eight` as a pun, since this is written with Java 8 features in mind. Also, the unit test spells out `CLI` in full because appending `Test` to *that* creates another word that some may find inappropriate...

Without further ado, what follows are the code for `Calculeightor` and `CalculeightorGUI`. For the review of the other code, please look at the [other review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88007/yet-another-java-cli-calculator).

General feedback I am looking for:

1. Any places where I can simplify the logic?
2. Are Javadocs clear and concise enough?
3. Any major faults?

<s>Specific feedback I am looking for</s> **It's Bounty Time**:

1. I intended to keep the `Calculeightor` interface generic enough so that I can potentially cater for other classes extending `Number`, but since I have nailed down my `Operator` `enum` to support only `Double`s, I have lost this flexibility. Would I be (marginally?) better off, for the purposes of this interface and the implementations, dropping the typed parameter and go with `Double` and `Operator` in it?
2. The reason behind the `private enum State` is to consolidate the toggling of buttons into a series of steps that a developer can tell at a glance. As such, places that require a 'refresh of the GUI simply calls `updateState()`, instead of scattering the toggling logic around. Is this an OK approach, or are there alternatives to this that I should be aware of?
3. Is there a simpler way of creating key bindings inside the GUI implementation?

---

### `Calculeightor`

```
/**
 * A lightweight interface for describing how values can be appended into a stream and
 * then reduced to a single result given an operator.
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
public interface Calculeightor<T extends Number> {

    /**
     * @param value the value to add
     */
    void appendValue(T value);

    Stream<T> getValues();

    /**
     * @param operator the operator to use
     */
    void setOperator(BinaryOperator<T> operator);

    BinaryOperator<T> getOperator();

    /**
     * @return the result
     */
    default T getResult() {
        return getValues().reduce(getOperator()).get();
    }

    /**
     * @param value the value to display
     * @return a formatted {@link String} without trailing decimals if possible
     */
    default String display(T value) {
        return value.doubleValue() % 1 == 0 ? Integer.toString(value.intValue())
                : value.toString();
    }
}
```

### `CalculeightorGUI`

```
/**
 * The GUI implementation of {@link Calculeightor}.
 * <p>
 * The input sequence is enforced by enabling different buttons at each stage. The
 * stages are:
 * <ol>
 * <li>Get a number</li>
 * <li>Select an operator</li>
 * <li>Get the next number</li>
 * <li>Press the {@code "="} button to calculate the answer</li>
 * </ol>
 * Results are displayed as integer values if possible.
 */
public class CalculeightorGUI extends JFrame implements Calculeightor<Double> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

    private final Collection<JButton> numbers = new HashSet<>();
    private final Collection<JButton> operators = new HashSet<>();
    private final JButton equalsOp = equalsButton();
    private final JLabel label = new JLabel();
    private final List<Double> inputs = new ArrayList<>(2);
    private BinaryOperator<Double> operator;
    private State state;

    /**
     * Controls what {@link Component}s need to be configured at different stages of
     * receiving input by calling {@link State#set(CalculeightorGUI)}. As such, the
     * values represent what <em>has already</em> happened, and <em>has been</em> set.
     */
    private enum State {
        INIT {
            @Override
            void set(CalculeightorGUI instance) {
                toggle(instance.operators.stream(), Stream.of(instance.equalsOp));
                instance.label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            }
        },
        FIRST_OPERAND {
            @Override
            void set(CalculeightorGUI instance) {
                toggle(instance.numbers.stream(), instance.operators.stream());
            }
        },
        OPERATOR {
            @Override
            void set(CalculeightorGUI instance) {
                toggle(instance.numbers.stream(), instance.operators.stream());
            }
        },
        SECOND_OPERAND {
            @Override
            void set(CalculeightorGUI instance) {
                toggle(instance.numbers.stream(), Stream.of(instance.equalsOp));
            }
        },
        EQUALS {
            @Override
            void set(CalculeightorGUI instance) {
                toggle(instance.numbers.stream(), Stream.of(instance.equalsOp));
                instance.inputs.clear();
            }
        };

        State next() {
            return this == EQUALS ? FIRST_OPERAND : values()[ordinal() + 1];
        }

        abstract void set(CalculeightorGUI instance);

        private static <T extends Component> void toggle(Stream<T>... components) {
            Stream.of(components).flatMap(Function.identity())
                    .forEach(c -> c.setEnabled(!c.isEnabled()));
        }
    }

    public CalculeightorGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle(getClass().getSimpleName());
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        Stream.of(numbersPanel(), operatorsPanel(), panelOf(Stream.of(equalsOp, label)))
                .forEach(this::add);
        updateState();
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Updates the latest state and also the input configuration.
     */
    private void updateState() {
        (state = state == null ? State.INIT : state.next()).set(this);
    }

    private JPanel numbersPanel() {
        return panelOf(IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 9).boxed(), numbers, event -> {
            Double value = Double.valueOf((((JButton) event.getSource()).getText()));
            appendValue(value);
            label.setText(Integer.toString(value.intValue()));
            updateState();
        });
    }

    private JPanel operatorsPanel() {
        return panelOf(Stream.of(Operator.values()), operators, event -> {
            String value = ((JButton) event.getSource()).getText();
            setOperator(Operator.of(value));
            label.setText(value);
            updateState();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Creates {@link JButton}s representing each stream's elements.
     *
     * @param values
     * @param collection the collection to add the created {@link JButton}s to
     * @param listener the listener to receive events from the {@link JButton}s
     * @return a single-row {@link JPanel} containing the created {@link JButton}s
     */
    private <T> JPanel panelOf(Stream<T> values, Collection<JButton> collection,
            ActionListener listener) {
        return panelOf(values.map(v -> createButton(v, listener))
                .peek(collection::add));
    }

    /**
     * @param components
     * @return a single-row {@link JPanel} containing the {@link Component}s
     */
    private static <T extends Component> JPanel panelOf(Stream<T> components) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
        components.forEach(panel::add);
        return panel;
    }

    private JButton equalsButton() {
        return createButton("=", event -> {
            Double value = getResult();
            label.setText(display(value));
            label.setForeground(value.isInfinite() ? Color.RED : Color.BLACK);
            updateState();
        });
    }

    /**
     * @param input the input to use
     * @param listener the listener to receive events from the {@link JButton}
     * @return a {@link JButton} with the input as its text and a key binding of the
     *         first character while the window is in focus
     */
    private static JButton createButton(Object input, ActionListener listener) {
        String text = input.toString();
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.addActionListener(listener);
        button.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
                KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(text.charAt(0)), text);
        button.getActionMap().put(text, getAction(button));
        return button;
    }

    /**
     * @param button the {@link JButton} to configure for
     * @return an {@link Action} that clicks the button
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private static Action getAction(JButton button) {
        return new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                button.doClick();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void appendValue(Double value) {
        inputs.add(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Stream<Double> getValues() {
        return inputs.stream();
    }

    @Override
    public void setOperator(BinaryOperator<Double> operator) {
        this.operator = operator;
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<Double> getOperator() {
        return operator;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CalculeightorGUI();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters, my `main()` method should use [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> { new CalculeightorGUI(); });
}
```

I should also use my `State` `enum` to handle the display of inputs, for example I can have the following two `static` helper methods in the `enum`:

```
private static void display(CalculeightorGUI instance, Double value) {
    instance.label.setText(Integer.valueOf(value.intValue()).toString());
}

private static void display(CalculeightorGUI instance, String text) {
    instance.label.setText(text);
}
```

And the code for `FIRST_OPERAND`, `OPERATOR` and `SECOND_OPERAND` can be modified as such:

```
FIRST_OPERAND {
    @Override
    void set(CalculeightorGUI instance) {
        toggle(instance.numbers.stream(), instance.operators.stream());
        List<Double> inputs = instance.inputs;
        display(instance, inputs.get(inputs.size() - 1));
    }
},
OPERATOR {
    @Override
    void set(CalculeightorGUI instance) {
        toggle(instance.numbers.stream(), instance.operators.stream());
        display(instance, instance.operator.toString());
    }
},
SECOND_OPERAND {
    @Override
    void set(CalculeightorGUI instance) {
        toggle(instance.numbers.stream(), Stream.of(instance.equals));
        List<Double> inputs = instance.inputs;
        display(instance, inputs.get(inputs.size() - 1));
    }
}
```

This simplifies (*slightly*) my `ActionListener`s for the numbers and operators buttons:

```
private JPanel numbersPanel() {
    return panelOf(IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 9).boxed(), numbers, event -> {
        appendValue(Double.valueOf((((JButton) event.getSource()).getText())));
        updateState();
    });
}

private JPanel operatorsPanel() {
    return panelOf(Stream.of(Operator.values()), operators, event -> {
        setOperator(Operator.of(((JButton) event.getSource()).getText()));
        updateState();
    });
}
```

**edit**

Actually, why stop at the operands and operator when I can do the same thing for the equals button too?

I figured I can also create a `Double result` field in my class:

```
private final List<Double> inputs = new ArrayList<>(2);
private Double result = null; // to store the result
private State state = null;
private Operator operator;
```

Then my `equalsButton()` can be simplified as such:

```
private JButton equalsButton() {
    JButton button = createButton("=", event -> {
        result = inputs.stream().reduce(operator).get();
    });
    return button;
}
```

The `Operator.EQUALS` implementation then becomes:

```
EQUALS {
    @Override
    void set(CalculeightorGUI instance) {
        toggle(instance.numbers.stream(), Stream.of(instance.equals));
        instance.label.setText(instance.display(instance.result));
        instance.label.setForeground(
                instance.result.isInfinite() ? Color.RED : Color.BLACK);
        instance.inputs.clear();
    }
}
```

The `equalsButton()` changes above does not call the `updateState()`, ditto for the `ActionListener`s specified in `numbersPanel()` and `operatorsPanel()`, because I can move that to my `createButton()` code to 'compose' invoking the `listener` argument with calling `updateState()` too. This means I have to un-`static` the method `createButton()` itself.

```
private JButton createButton(Object input, ActionListener listener) {
    String text = input.toString();
    JButton button = new JButton(text);
    button.addActionListener(event -> {
        listener.actionPerformed(event); updateState(); });
    button.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(text.charAt(0)), text);
    button.getActionMap().put(text, getAction(button));
    return button;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> > public static void main(String[] args) {
> >     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> { new CalculeightorGUI(); }); }
> ```

The content of your main can actually be just `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(CalculeightorGUI::new);`

Comment: +1 on your answer, will leave my own answer as the original so as not to diminish your input here. :D

Comment: Thanks, I really enjoy both your question and answer! Makes for a good study.