# Yet Another Java CLI Calculator

Tags: java, calculator, community-challenge

In the spirit of [April 2015 Community Challenge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5174/april-2015-community-challenge?cb=1), I have created *two* Java-based calculators with the following codebase layout:

- An interface `Calculeightor` for describing how values can be appended into a stream and then reduced to a single result given an operator.
- An enum `Operator` to represent the operators.
- The GUI implementation `CalculeightorGUI`.
- The CLI implementation `CalculeightorCLI`.
- A unit test for the CLI implementation `CalculeightorCommandLineInterfaceTest`.

The name uses `eight` as a pun, since this is written with Java 8 features in mind. Also, the unit test spells out `CLI` in full because appending `Test` to *that* creates another word that some may find inappropriate...

Without further ado, what follows are the code for `Operator`, `CalculeightorCLI` and `CalculeightorCommandLineInterfaceTest`. For the review of the other code, please look at the [other review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88005/yet-another-java-gui-calculator).

General feedback I am looking for:

1. Any places where I can simplify the logic?
2. Are Javadocs clear and concise enough?
3. Any major faults?

---

### `Operator`

```
public enum Operator implements BinaryOperator<Double> {
    ADD {
        @Override
        public Double apply(Double t, Double u) {
            return Double.valueOf(t.doubleValue() + u.doubleValue());
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "+";
        }
    },
    SUBTRACT {
        @Override
        public Double apply(Double t, Double u) {
            return Double.valueOf(t.doubleValue() - u.doubleValue());
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "-";
        }
    },
    MULTIPLY {
        @Override
        public Double apply(Double t, Double u) {
            return Double.valueOf(t.doubleValue() * u.doubleValue());
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "*";
        }
    },
    DIVIDE {
        @Override
        public Double apply(Double t, Double u) {
            return Double.valueOf(t.doubleValue() / u.doubleValue());
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "/";
        }
    },
    MODULUS {
        @Override
        public Double apply(Double t, Double u) {
            return Double.valueOf(t.intValue() % u.intValue());
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "%";
        }
    },
    EXPONENT {
        @Override
        public Double apply(Double t, Double u) {
            return Double.valueOf(Math.pow(t.doubleValue(), u.doubleValue()));
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "^";
        }
    };

    static final Map<String, Operator> SYMBOLS = Stream.of(values()).collect(
            Collectors.toMap(Object::toString, Function.identity()));

    static Operator of(String operator) {
        return SYMBOLS.get(operator);
    }
}
```

### `CalculeightorCLI`

```
/**
 * The CLI implementation of {@link Calculeightor}.
 * <p>
 * There is no limitation placed on the number of
 * inputs before entering the operator to use.
 */
public class CalculeightorCLI implements Calculeightor<Double> {

    public static final Map<String, Operator> OPERATORS = getOperators();
    public static final String RESULT_PREFIX = "Result: ";
    public static final String END_INPUT = "e";
    private static final int MIN_VALUES = 2;

    private final List<Double> inputs = new ArrayList<>();
    private BinaryOperator<Double> operator;

    private static Map<String, Operator> getOperators() {
        return EnumSet.complementOf(EnumSet.of(Operator.DIVIDE, Operator.MODULUS))
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Object::toString, Function.identity()));
    }

    public void calculate(InputStream source, OutputStream out) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(source);
                @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                PrintStream printer = new PrintStream(out)) {
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String input = scanner.next().trim();
                if (endInput(input)) {
                    return;
                } else if (isOperator(input)) {
                    if (acceptOperator(input)) {
                        setOperator(OPERATORS.get(input));
                        showOutput(printer);
                    }
                } else {
                    acceptValue(input);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean endInput(String input) {
        return input.endsWith(END_INPUT);
    }

    private boolean isOperator(String input) {
        return OPERATORS.containsKey(input);
    }

    private boolean acceptOperator(String input) {
        if (inputs.size() < MIN_VALUES) {
            System.err.printf("Minimum %d integers before calculation.%n",
                    Integer.valueOf(MIN_VALUES));
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void acceptValue(String input) {
        try {
            appendValue(Double.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(input)));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("Not an integer, ignored: " + input);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Writes the result onto the {@link OutputStream} via a {@link PrintStream}, and
     * then clear the inputs.
     *
     * @param out the {@link OutputStream} to use
     */
    private void showOutput(PrintStream out) {
        if (operator == null) {
            return;
        }
        out.println(RESULT_PREFIX + display(getResult()));
        inputs.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void appendValue(Double value) {
        inputs.add(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Stream<Double> getValues() {
        return inputs.stream();
    }

    @Override
    public void setOperator(BinaryOperator<Double> operator) {
        this.operator = operator;
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<Double> getOperator() {
        return operator;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("Enter integers, any of %s as operators or '%s' to exit.%n",
                OPERATORS.keySet(), END_INPUT);
        new CalculeightorCLI().calculate(System.in, System.out);
    }

}
```

### `CalculeightorCommandLineInterfaceTest`

```
public class CalculeightorCommandLineInterfaceTest {

    enum TestCase {
        EXIT,
        INVALID_INPUTS("abc", "0.1", "0.0"),
        ONE_INTEGER("0"),
        ONE_INTEGER_AND_OPERATOR("0", "+"),
        ADD(Arrays.asList("6"), "1", "2", "3", "+"),
        SUBTRACT(Arrays.asList("-1"), "4", "5", "-"),
        MULTIPLY(Arrays.asList("42"), "6", "7", "*"),
        EXPONENT(Arrays.asList("134217728"), "8", "9", "^"),
        MULTI(Arrays.asList("21", "156"), "10", "11", "+", "-12", "-13", "*");

        private final List<String> expected;
        private final String[] inputs;

        private TestCase(String... inputs) {
            this(Collections.emptyList(), inputs);
        }

        private TestCase(List<String> expected, String... inputs) {
            this.expected = expected;
            this.inputs = inputs;
        }

        void doTest() {
            OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            new CalculeightorCLI().calculate(toInputStream(inputs), out);
            assertThat(parseOutput(out), equalTo(expected));
        }

        /**
         * @param inputs the inputs to use
         * @return an {@link InputStream} of the inputs
         */
        private static InputStream toInputStream(String... inputs) {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(Arrays.stream(inputs)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))
                    .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        }

        /**
         * @param out the output to parse
         * @return the {@link List} of calculation results
         */
        private static List<String> parseOutput(OutputStream out) {
            int prefix = CalculeightorCLI.RESULT_PREFIX.length();
            return Pattern.compile("\\v+").splitAsStream(out.toString().trim())
                    .map(i -> i.substring(prefix)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "test-cases")
    public Iterator<Object[]> getTestCases() {
        return Stream.of(TestCase.values()).map(t -> new Object[] { t }).iterator();
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "test-cases")
    public void test(TestCase testCase) {
        testCase.doTest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### enum improvements

I would use a constructor for your enum to make things more consise.

I would also use the `DoubleBinaryOperator` instead, which works directly with the primitive `double` type.

Additionally, you might as well make your `Operator of(String operator)` method *public* and your `SYMBOLS` map *private*.

Applying these changes will make your enum look like this:

```
public enum Operator implements DoubleBinaryOperator {
    ADD("+", (a, b) -> a + b),
    SUBTRACT("-", (a, b) -> a - b),
    MULTIPLY("*", (a, b) -> a * b),
    DIVIDE("+", (a, b) -> a / b),
    MODULUS("%", (a, b) -> a % b),
    EXPONENT("^", (a, b) -> Math.pow(a, b));

    private final String name;
    private final DoubleBinaryOperator op;

    private Operator(String name, DoubleBinaryOperator op) {
        this.name = name;
        this.op = op;
    }

    @Override
    public double applyAsDouble(double left, double right) {
        return op.applyAsDouble(left, right);
    }

    private static final Map<String, Operator> SYMBOLS = Stream.of(values()).collect(
        Collectors.toMap(Object::toString, Function.identity()));


    public static Operator of(String operator) {
        return SYMBOLS.get(operator);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```